# Bootstrap tooltip would not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Yes, i know this is a duplicate, but all the answers i've read didn't help me, i have a side by side working example, from w3school, it works, and mine doesn't, what i am trying to do is show a tooltip warning the user to use numbers only, but instead, it just refreshes the page.

This is my full html page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="Css/style.css"> /*---not using the bootstrap css because it messes up the form layout, so i copied every tooltip referenced block to my style.css instead.---*/
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var previous;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').tooltip(); 
        });
        //Buy Button JS code
        $(function () {
            $("#searchform").bind('submit', function () {
                var str = $('#search-form').val();
                if (str.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
                    $('#search-form').tooltip({title="You did good :)"});
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#search-form').tooltip({title="Please enter numbers ONLY !"});
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <form class="search-form" method="post" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" id="search-form" name="textbox" placeholder="Please enter your code" required/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btntxt">Validate</button>
        <div id="search_results"></div>

    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I didn't put the `data-toggle:"tooltip"` neither a `title:"sometitlehere"` in the element's options, because [i don't really need it](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_title&stacked=h).

Comment: button type is submit so it is refreshing page

Comment: How so ? i thought i made the js code check the input text before it does anything else.

Comment: Check if `bootstrap.min.js` is getting loaded.

Comment: `data-toggle="tooltip"` is exactly what shows / hides your tooltip.. in your case you should add it to the button and  change the type from `submit` to `button`, then, in javascript / jquery do something like `$(this).form().submit(). to submit the form if it passes your checks.

Comment: @Sahil how do i do that ? should i set an alert at the `$(document).ready(function(){` ?
@Spluf in the w3school example i linked (second link), they don't use it, and it works.

Comment: Does **js/tooltip.js** contain **bootstrap.min.js** code? If not then you can include it after **jquery.min.js**, `<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Sahil well i downloaded the whole repository and got the tooltip.js from there, but using your reference it is still the same result, here is my code so far: http://pastebin.com/J8L8dVTq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code,

```
//it should be title: and not title=
 $('#search-form').tooltip({title:"You did good :)"});
```

The above line initializes the tooltip once your code excutes.
After that if the tooltip title is updated, the tooltip is needed to be destroyed and re-initialized with new title.

```js
var previous;

        //Buy Button JS code
        $(function () {
            $("#searchform").bind('submit', function () {
              var newTooltip="";
                var str = $('#search-form').val();
                if (str.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
                    newTooltip = "You did good :)";
                }
                else
                {
                    newTooltip = 'Please enter numbers ONLY !';                     
                }
              
              $('#search-form').attr('title', newTooltip).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('setContent').tooltip('show');
              setTimeout(function(){
               $('#search-form').tooltip('hide').tooltip('destroy');
                }, 1500);
              
            });

          
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

/*---not using the bootstrap css because it messes up the form layout, so i copied every tooltip referenced block to my style.css instead.---*/

 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
    <form class="search-form" method="post" id="searchform">
        <input type="text" id="search-form" name="textbox" placeholder="Please enter your code" required/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btntxt">Validate</button>
        <div id="search_results"></div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok we are making progress, thanks, but now it requires me to re-hover over the input to show the tool tip, so i added `.tooltip('show`), but how to negate the hover event ? as you can see i want it to like, stay on for a few seconds then fade/disapear.

Comment: Thank you, now all i have left is to add an image to the title option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

are you initialising the tooltip in the js? - tooltips won't show unless you have this in the code:

```
$(function(){
 $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
 })
```

ok - I just looked at your code - you have :

```
$('.btn').tooltip();
```

listed in theree, but your button has the class "`btntxt`" and you are also trying to get a tooltip on the search form - but that has the id of "`search-form`" - neither of which will be affected by your tooltip declaration. Best to use the one I  gave in the is post so that all elements with tooltips can display them. Setting them to individual classes or ids is too restrictive if you forget that your class or id is not the same as the one listed in the js.

Comment: again, your line would ONLY work if i put the `data-toggle` on my element which i don't want to, although i tried changing that to `$("#search-form").tooltip();`, still refreshing and does nothing.EDIT: that was a typo, in my code it is correct, still nothing comes out of it.

Comment: then you will need to also declare the trigger for the tooltip ("hover" or click" )are the options i think

Comment: The whole point of my code is to not use the hover or click, but to forcibly show the tool tip as an error.

Comment: If this is simply to show an error message to the user then a tooltip may not be the best approach - you could simply have a div with the error and show / hide it depending on the validation of the code. A tooltip is really a UI / UX feature to include extra information about an element and is usually triggered by the user hovering over the element which then displays extra information. An error message is what you are trying to achieve here - not a tool tip

Comment: I thought it would look great and won't break the form or expand it, because the error is literally just a few words long, instead of creating a whole division that just collapases and expands, a nice small tooltip would do the job great. If you would like to take a look at the code as is: http://pastebin.com/J8L8dVTq

Comment: @Omarrrio, there are 2 ways to show a tooltip: 1. by javascript code, where you bind to an event like click, hover, etc adn 2. where you use attributes like data-toggle. You don't want to use any of it, then simply don't use a tooltip. Because you can't...

Comment: But Spluf, the example in W3 doesn't use the data toggle, although your comment in the question up top, how can i achieve that ? the check then submit ?

Comment: the w3 examples aren't always in full context. Anyway, in order to do the check, change the button type to button (because submit submits the form directly). Then do this: `$(".btntxt").click(function() {var val =  $("#searchform").text(); ` //check your val and do whatever you need with it, if it's ok then: `$(this).form().submit(); // if it's not ok, return false;});`

Comment: in your code, you don't really need to submit anyway, you are doing it already in your $.post() function. You just need to show the message.

Comment: @Spluf hummm but how do i make sure that the Enter key would work the same as button, because in my previous code, i bound submit to the button, so Enter key was the submit key, but in your new code, it just binds the button click event to the function, wouldn't that make the enter key function worthless ?

Comment: `$('#searchbox input').bind('keypress', function(e) { var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
 } });` in order to bind to the enter and then you can remove the button entirely and add that code in this block on the //do something part. You can also keep both of them if that's what you want

Answer (score 1):

You are using form so you need to return true or false on validate action so your code should be like

```
 if (str.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
                $('#search-form').tooltip({title="You did good :)"});
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#search-form').tooltip({title="Please enter numbers ONLY !"});
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have this order to your scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Does the tooltip.js require jquery? - if so you may need to invert that order

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
```